# Rails validation errors on forms for json requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form that uses json

```
<%= form_for([@category, @key], url: guide_categories_keycreate_path(category_id: params[:id]), remote: true, :authenticity_token => true) do |f| %>
   <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

   <%= f.label :name, "Key name" %>
   <%= f.text_field :name %>

    <%= f.select :key_type, [['Value', 1], ['Text', 2], ['Image', 3]] %>

   <%= f.submit "Next", :value => "Add New Key"  %>
<% end %>
```

If the submission is invalid I want to have a standard error message of "That name is already taken or is blank". Currently I have the basic `render: json` if the form didn't save. I've tried

```
format.json {  render :json { :message ""That name is already taken or is blank"} }
```

but that doesn't work and was just a complete guess.

Comment: There's nothing in your posted form that uses JSON. That's an HTML form. Where does the JSON come into it, and why do you want to use it?

Comment: It's not working (in the first place) because your render call is a complete mess, I'm afraid. The correct format would be: `format.json { render json: {message: "That name is already taken or is blank"} }`. That doesn't guarantee that it will actually work, though.

Comment: Does your model have any validation? This is an odd place to define your error message.

Comment: Yes it does have validations. I don't know how else to have the errors shown, that was just a stab in the dark. If the form failed it would be one of those reasons so I thought to put that message up upon failure.

Answer (score 1):

On your controller, try using this

```
format.json {  render :json => { :message => "That name is already taken or is blank"} }
```

Comment: Gives a syntax error `syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting '}'`

Comment: format.json { render :json **=>** { :message => "That name is already taken or is blank"} }

Comment: No syntax error but the message isn't displayed. But I think thats because it has no were to display. Should I add a div or something for it to show up in?

Comment: add `format.html {render :new}` before the `format.json...`